# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'member_id' when reading text file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read in a text file with two columns, in numpy/pandas.

I get an error on both columns, `Member_ID, Home_ownership`, however, after adding `delimiter=','`, the issue disappears for `Home_ownership` column.

Here's my code. Based on online videos I tried adding `encoder='latin'`, but it didn't work.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

home_ownership = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\Shlesha13\Desktop\mais-202-coding-challenge-f2019-master\home_ownership_data.csv', delimiter=',')
print (home_ownership)
```

Comment: Please provide a traceback.

Comment: whats the csv file look like..whats in it

Comment: Hey, here is the link to csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TLoze56FhyQoIMkC6Pvz9m-AsVe5cbX_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be sure to state your issue clearly ("reading in a text (CSV) file with two columns"); also to tag clearly (this should have been tagged 'pandas' and has nothing to do with Spyder, Spyder is only the IDE, it doesn't cause errors)

Answer (score 2):

You can read your CSV using numpy or using pandas.

```py
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

path = 'home_ownership_data.csv'
arr = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',', dtype=None)
df = pd.read_csv(path)
print(df)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried, didn't affect the result. tried placing it both before and after calling the file. any other thoughts?

Comment: Ah, it's because your 2nd column has string values. Let me edit my answer.